# al intentar correr el programa se abre un archivo cpp

Tags: c++, array, delete

¿Alguien sabe por qué al intentar correr el programa se me abre un archivo `cpp` llamado `delete_scalar.cpp`?, mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include "herramienta.h"

class contenedor{
private:
    herramienta** vec;
    int cantidad;
    int tamannio;
public:
    contenedor(int Ptamannio) {
        tamannio = Ptamannio;
        cantidad = 0;
        vec = new herramienta * [tamannio];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamannio; i++) {
            vec[i] = nullptr;
        }
    }

    ~contenedor() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamannio; i++) {
            delete vec[i];
        }
        cantidad = 0;
        delete[] vec;
    }

    bool agrega(herramienta * ob) {
        if (cantidad < tamannio) {
            vec[cantidad] = ob;
            cantidad++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    string toString() {
        stringstream s;
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
            s << vec[i]->toString() << endl;
        }
        return s.str();
    }



};
```

según estuve tratando de resolver el error, puede que se deba a estas líneas:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamannio; i++) {
  delete vec[i];
}
```

porque las borre y ya el programa no me tiro ningún error, pero supongo que borrar estas líneas no es la solución ya que estaría dejando los punteros que están dentro del array sin eliminar, o no se si con delete[] vec; automáticamente se borran (no creo).

Comment: Por regla general, con un mismo punto, si usaste `new` debes usar `delete` y si usaste `new[]` debes usar `delete[]`. Por cierto, qué quieres decir con que se abre el archivo **delete_scalar.cpp**?

Comment: @Mateo lo de delete_scalar.cpp era que se abría otro archivo, aparte que visual me decía que estaba haciendo una infracción de escritura (no escribiré todo el aviso de error) y se activaba un breakpoint, y si continúa se corrompia la memoria, el error era que en el arreglo metía objetos estáticos y luego al llamarse el destructor y que un objeto estático se eliminará con delete ocasionaba el error.

Comment: Aparte que haces el for hasta i<tamanio asumiendo que tu vector esta lleno pero debería ser hasta cantidad ya que ese es el que indica hastabque índice del vector tiene datos, de lo contrario puedes estar haciendo delete a nullptr